# PCB layout toner transfer - ink printer

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I use iron to transfer toner to the copper board, and have been using laser printer. I saw some discussion on the net that it is also possible to use use ink printer if the ink is a good quality. I have a HP inkjet printer and use original cartridges. Could someone explain if (how) it is possible to use the ink on the toner transfer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do with an ink printer is to produce a **mask** by printing onto a transparent (ink compatible) sheet. This is then used to control the exposure of photo sensitized board under a UV light.

Laser toner works as a transfer method because the 'ink' is actually a thermo-plastic (i.e. not 'ink' as in the inkjet) that can be re-heated with an iron and made to stick onto the copper surface as a resist.

Comment: I have seen where some folks are direct printing special ink onto the board from a modified ink jet.

Comment: @ErikFriesen Yes, if the ink is substituted. It needs to be non water/organic solvent based as it will have to survive the etching process after drying. Not something I would do personally. A 'standard' ink from an inkjet wouldn't work.